How to compile Samsung kernel source to a bootable image for Android 14 devices
I'm working with the Samsung kernel source and following the official instructions to build it. So far, I've managed to compile the kernel and produce an Image.gz file, but I'm unsure how to package this into a boot.img file that I can flash onto a device.
Here's the process I've followed so far:

Toolchain Setup: Downloaded and extracted the appropriate toolchain from Samsung's official site and placed it in the specified directory.

Environment Setup:

Changed to the kernel source directory:
cd kernel-5.10


Ran the gen_build_config.py script to generate the config:
python scripts/gen_build_config.py --kernel-defconfig a15_00_defconfig --kernel-defconfig-overlays "entry_level.config" -m user -o ../out/target/product/a15/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/build.config


Exported the build environment variables:
export ARCH=arm64
export CROSS_COMPILE="aarch64-linux-gnu-"
export CROSS_COMPILE_COMPAT="arm-linux-gnueabi-"
export OUT_DIR="../out/target/product/a15/obj/KERNEL_OBJ"
export DIST_DIR="../out/target/product/a15/obj/KERNEL_OBJ"
export BUILD_CONFIG="../out/target/product/a15/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/build.config"




Build: Ran the build script, resulting in the following output:
cd ../kernel
./build/build.sh

This generated an Image.gz file in out/target/product/a15/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/kernel-5.10/arch/arm64/boot.


My Question:
How can I package this Image.gz file into a boot.img that can be flashed onto a Samsung device? Is there an additional tool or specific steps to achieve this?
Thanks for any guidance or examples!
